# Geofence background app possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I'm not sure if Apple allows this.  Can I make an app that uses geofence to track how long you have been inside a geofence location and when you exited?

I know I can create alerts like the Reminders app, but how can I feed these alerts back into my app so I can see how long i've been in the geofence?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app can be notified when the user enters or leaves an area you designate. Read about [Location Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). You can't/shouldn't try to do much when you get such a notification, though -- just save the information. Don't try to send messages to a server or something like that -- save that for when your app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

A geofence event can be triggered, and the callback code snippet of an App can be executed not only in the background state but even in killed state when the App has fully stopped.